# How do I call a string thats displayed within a method into another class?

Tags: c#, string, format-string

I am having trouble displaying a method that contains a string into a different class.

Main Program

```
 Vehicle car = new Vehicle("Toyota", "Camry", 500, "Red", 30, 3, 2);
            car.Display();
```

Vehicle

```
public void Display()
{
    string output = string.Format("MK: {0} MDL: {1} WGT: {2} CLR: {3} MPG: {4} ",
                make, model, weight, color, mpg, tank.GetDisplayString());

    System.Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

GasTank

```
public string GetDisplayString()
{
    string output = string.Format("TANK: Cap: {0} LEVEL: {1}", tankCapacity, tankLevel);

    return output;  
}

public void display()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(GetDisplayString());
}
```

Comment: Can you describe more in details of the problem you are facing?

Comment: You don't have a placeholder for the string `tank.GetDisplayString()`. Try `string output = string.Format("MK: {0} MDL: {1} WGT: {2} CLR: {3} MPG: {4} {5}",
                make, model, weight, color, mpg, tank.GetDisplayString());`

Comment: It seems that you are passing 6 additional parameters to the `string.Format`, but you are only using `{0]` to `{4}` missing `{5}`.

Comment: @Ruzihm THANK YOU SO MUCH. That would've been the last thing I would've tried. I was definitely making the problem way more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: Can you explain better in which method is the issue? From where this variables (make, model, weight, color, mpg, tank.GetDisplayString()) come? Is tank a object of the type GasTank? How is it instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bad design. Class should have as least responsibilities as possible, so displaying itself to user shouldn't be one of them.

Also, in `Vehicle.Display` method, you don't use `tank.GetDisplayString()`

Also you have "display" methods, which are unnecessary, i.e. `ToString` method, inherited from `object` should return "string presentation" of your object, so you should override it.

I suggest cleaner approach:

Vehicle

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // where tank.ToString() should go? It is not used here...
    return string.Format("MK: {0} MDL: {1} WGT: {2} CLR: {3} MPG: {4} ",
        make, model, weight, color, mpg, tank.ToString());
    // also you can use interpolated string
    // return $"MK: {make} MDL: {model} WGT: {weight} CLR: {color} MPG: {mpg} ";
}
```

GasTank

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("TANK: Cap: {0} LEVEL: {1}", tankCapacity, tankLevel);
}

public void display()
{
   System.Console.WriteLine(GetDisplayString());
}
```

Then, to display your classes, you can use simply:

```
Console.WriteLine(myVahicle.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(myGasTank.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string.Format`'s format string, in your `Vehicle` class's display method, is missing the 5th argument symbol, `{5}`. To fix this you can either just append `{5}` to the format string:

```
string output = string.Format("MK: {0} MDL: {1} WGT: {2} CLR: {3} MPG: {4} {5}",
                make, model, weight, color, mpg, tank.GetDisplayString());
```

add it separately:

```
string output = string.Format("MK: {0} MDL: {1} WGT: {2} CLR: {3} MPG: {4} ",
                make, model, weight, color, mpg) + tank.GetDisplayString();
```

or format it using `$`:

```
string output = $"MK: {make} MDL: {model} WGT: {weight} CLR: {color} MPG: {mpg} {tank.GetDisplayString()}"; //This is the same as string.Format just a bit more condensed
```